# How to properly protect company laptop on a business trip to China

Tags: defense, corporate-policy

This question ([How safe are employee laptops in China against International corporate espionage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106039/how-safe-are-employee-laptops-in-china-against-international-corporate-espionage)) got me thinking - what is the proper way to go on a business trip to China and protect your laptop. What are best practices and no-gos?

Is it just China or there are other countries that people should pay special attention to?

The mentioned existing question have nice answers but still seems to focus specifically on the specific scenario. I am looking for a more general best practices in such cases.

Comment: You have 2 different questions and you'll need to settle on one. We have a lot of material here on how to compute safely in hostile areas. So, that part is answered (i.e. take a disposable laptop). The already-compromised device is a totally different topic. Is that what you want to know? The fact that there was some compromise in the past doesn't change the travel part. Being physically in the country that compromised a device doesn't change anything.